# how to remove delay of a signal using verilog code

Tags: verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have a data signal start at 1400ns and end at 2000ns. i want that signal to start at 100ns.how to do that in verilog?.please help me.i'm new to the verilog code.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please post your code, so that it is easy to look at the problem. 
Also, are you intending to do a synthesizable verilog code as delays are non-synthesizable.

Assuming it is a part of testbench, I would do something like this

```
initial
   #100 signal = value;
   ...
```